# Allow leading '#' in P.O. Box Regex (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have a P.O. Box regex which is working great, but a customer has run into a situation where they need a leading '#'.

Here is my regex:

```
text.search(/^ *((#\d+)|((box|bin)[-. \/\\]?\d+)|(.*p[ \.]? ?(o|0)[-. \/\\]? *-?((box|bin)|b|(#|num)?\d+))|(p(ost)? *(o(ff(ice)?)?)? *((box|bin)|b)? *\d+)|(p *-?\/?(o)? *-?box)|post office box|((box|bin)|b) *(number|num|#)? *\d+|(num|number|#) *\d+)/i)
```

An example address which is causing the validator to fail is formatted like this:

```
#1-322 Brooke Street
```

How can I allow addresses like these with my current regex setup?

I've built a plunker with Angular. Input some text into the box, and the validator will change from true to false appropriately.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fpLmZQhRryBC3Z3ArZwV?p=preview

Comment: If the point of the regex is to validate if the text *matches*, then your plunker example is logically backwards.  I can validate "Little Bo Peep" as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this to accept a single # in the start as a valid value.

```
$scope.validateText = function () {
    if ($scope.text.search(/^ *((?#\d+)|((box|bin)[-. \/\\]?\d+)|(.*p[ \.]? ?(o|0)[-. \/\\]? *-?((box|bin)|b|(#|num)?\d+))|(p(ost)? *(o(ff(ice)?)?)? *((box|bin)|b)? *\d+)|(p *-?\/?(o)? *-?box)|post office box|((box|bin)|b) *(number|num|#)? *\d+|(num|number|#) *\d+)/i) !== -1) {
    $scope.valid = false;
    } else {
    $scope.valid = true; 
    }
}
```

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/i5f3vbGWB6SQ0bVRxGNV?p=preview